# Repeater does not show anything after second set of data binding

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, webforms, repeater

I have the following repeater inside an ASCX file:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <ul class="formList">
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li><a href="plugins/umbracocontour/editForm.aspx?guid=<%# ((Umbraco.Forms.Core.Form)Container.DataItem).Id %>"
                    class="form">
                    <%# ((Umbraco.Forms.Core.Form)Container.DataItem).Name %></a> <small><a href="plugins/umbracocontour/editForm.aspx?guid=<%# ((Umbraco.Forms.Core.Form)Container.DataItem).Id %>">
                        Open form designer</a> <a href="plugins/umbracocontour/editFormEntries.aspx?guid=<%# ((Umbraco.Forms.Core.Form)Container.DataItem).Id %>">
                            View entries</a> </small></li>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </ul>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

It is populated with data via a method named `ShowAllForms()`

```
private void ShowAllForms()
{
    using (var formStorage = new FormStorage())
    {
        var list = formStorage.GetAllForms(false).OrderBy(f => f.Name).Where(form => Security.HasAccessToForm(form.Id)).ToList();

        this.repeater1.DataSource = list;
        this.repeater1.DataBind();

        if (list.Count == 0)
        {
            this.paneBrowse.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

and `SearchForms:

```
private void SearchForms()
{
    var forms =
        this.formRepository.GetFormByFreeText(this.txtFormSearch.Text).Where(form => Security.HasAccessToForm(form.Id)).
            ToList();

    this.repeater1.DataSource = forms;
    this.repeater1.DataBind(); 
}
```

`ShowAllForms()` is called in `Page_Load`, if there has not been a postback, and also in the click event for the "Show All Forms" button. `SearchForms()` is called in the postback for the "Search Forms" button.

As a non-admin user, when I view the list of forms I see a whole bunch of them initially. I then search for a form via it's name which should return no items. So far so good. I then click the "Show All Forms" button which will execute `ShowAllForms()`, which is what was called to show all the forms in the first place.

However, when called a second time, `ShowAllForms()` does not show any form data in the repeater. To clarify, I can see that there are items returned in the `forms` variable, so the collection is not empty, and yet none of those items appear in the repeater.

I'm puzzled as to what could be going on here.

EDIT:

OnLoad event for the page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.ShowAllForms();    
    }
}
```

OnInit:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.formRepository = TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.Current.Resolve<IFormRepository>();
}
```

Comment: Can you show some more code please? PageLoad and OnInit for the page?

Comment: I have added the code for those events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is here:

```
    if (list.Count == 0)
    {
        this.paneBrowse.Visible = false;
    }
```

I don't see where you set `paneBrowse`'s visiblity to true again.

A quick fix would be:

```
    this.paneBrowse.Visible == (list.Count > 0);
```